# Go - Distinguishing between user input of just numbers and everything else

Tags: go

I am trying to get the code to loop if the number entered is below 600 and to loop if the input contains letters and symbols. I just cannot do it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)


func main() {
    fmt.Println("How far in metres are the people away from the spacecraft?")
    var people string
    fmt.Scanf("%s",&people)
      number, _ := strconv.Atoi(people)
      for number < 600 {
        if (number < 0 || number > 0 || people == "0"){
          fmt.Println("Too Close\nTry Again")
        var people string
        fmt.Scanf("%s",&people)
        number, _ := strconv.Atoi(people)
            fmt.Println(number)
          }else{
            fmt.Println("Only Number Please\nTry Again")
          var people string
          fmt.Scanf("%s",&people)
          number, _ := strconv.Atoi(people)
            fmt.Println(number)
            }

      }

fmt.Println("BLAST OFF !!!")
}
```

Comment: Atoi returns two values. The second one, which you are ignoring, is an error. You should check if that error is not nil, in that case it was probably not a number.

Comment: eugenioy is correct. Some other languages have exceptions that make the program stop working if you don't handle them. You need to ensure that you handle the errors returned from functions/methods in Go, else your program won't behave in a way that you can understand.

Answer (score 0):

eugenioy and Chrono Kitsune are correct.
To clarify what they are saying in code, here is an example:

```
var people string
var err error
var number int
for {
    fmt.Scanf("%s",&people)
    number, err = strconv.Atoi(people)
    if err == nil {
        break
    }
    fmt.Println("Not a number, please try again")
}
fmt.Println(number)
```